# HKStatisticsCollectionQuery works for one day and then stops. How to keep update handler working indefinitely?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

The goal of this code is to monitor the users active calories burned each day. Right now the code works perfectly on day 1. The users calories burned on that day are fetched and the calorie count updates throughout the day. However, the next day the code stops working and it just displayed the users active calories burned on day 1. How can this code be fixed so that the update handler continues to fetch the users active calories burned every day without stopping at the end of the first day.

```
    func getSteps() -> Void {

    guard let energyBurnedType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .activeEnergyBurned) else {
        fatalError("*** Unable to get the step count type ***")
    }

    var interval = DateComponents()
    interval.hour = 24

    let calendar = Calendar.current

    let anchorDate = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date())

    let query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery.init(quantityType: energyBurnedType,
                                              quantitySamplePredicate: nil,
                                              options: .cumulativeSum,
                                              anchorDate: anchorDate!,
                                              intervalComponents: interval)

    query.initialResultsHandler = {
     query, results, error in

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let startDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
        results?.enumerateStatistics(from: startDate,
                                  to: Date(), with: { (result, false) in
                                    self.moveResult = (Int(result.sumQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.kilocalorie()) ?? 0))})
    }
 }

query.statisticsUpdateHandler = {
    query, statistics, results, error in

    print("update handler set")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        // in order to fix problem of steps not updating at the start of new day I tried using Calendar.current
        let currentDay = Calendar.current
        let startDate = currentDay.startOfDay(for: Date())
        results?.enumerateStatistics(from: startDate,
                                     to: Date(), with: { (result, false) in
    self.moveResult = (Int(result.sumQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.kilocalorie()) ?? 0))})
    }
}


 healthStore.execute(query)}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the problem:

```
let startDate = currentDay.startOfDay(for: Date())
```

Start date should not be today date.

Try to make this date few days before today.

For example:

Setup startDate to be 3 days before today

```
query.initialResultsHandler = {
 query, results, error in

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -3, to: Date())
    results?.enumerateStatistics(from: startDate,
                              to: Date(), with: { (result, false) in
                                self.moveResult = (Int(result.sumQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.kilocalorie()) ?? 0))})
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Maks. I'm still uncertain if the problem is currentDay or Date() or both? I'm a beginning coder and am new to working with dates. Do you have a suggested fix for this line?

Comment: @RyanMartinson I've updated an answer, please check it, this should do the work

Comment: So yesterday, I updated the initial results handler and update handler with the code you suggested. But after midnight the code was still unable to query and update steps during the new day. I'm still not sure why this is occurring.